# django received the post value is not complete

Tags: python, django

i posted the data to a django view function but the data seem not completion,i had check the data in my chrome browser,it worked,but when i viewed the post data in django ,it not worked! i think the data that i post is filtered by the django.

here is the data in my browser:

```
1$精品红茶$01-12 22:06$1
```

here is the data received in django view function

```
u'1$精品红茶$01-12'
```

there is any way that i can get the completion data from view function?

Comment: I would just like to point out that on this site you are supposed to write (all) your posts in English. Please include a translation of your data (underneath), so that we can all understand, thank you for your time and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Mango - Translation of the data doesn't matter, its irrelevant what value the data has in regards to the question being asked. Especially when double-byte characters may be the issue

Comment: @Mango The problem should be explained in English, but not the actual data. When you have a unicode problem, how can you explain your problem with plain English?

Comment: _How_ do you post the data? And how do you then use the data in the view?

Answer (score 0):

I did a test in my computer, i could not rebuild this problem. Here is the message i got from page.

```
Insert an user: Name:1$精品红茶$01-12 22:06$1 - Email:test@123345456.com - Password:123456
```

I set up the template html files as UTF-8

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

AND I also set the project files encoding as 'UTF-8'.  Maybe you can try this way.